# ERROR: channel-add: Channel 'community' already exist! when trying to upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my installation of Magento 1.8.0.0 to 1.9 via SSH, when I run

**./mage mage-setup .**

I receive:

> Running initial setup...
>
> Success
>
> Success
>
> Error:
>
> channel-add: Channel 'community' already exist!

Any thoughts on what I should do next?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checkout this forum post from others who have had your problem. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/217347/

Some possible solutions include:

> in the magento directory :
>
> `./mage channel-delete community`
>
> `./mage mage-setup`
>
> Then add the extension again via magento connect

and

> Go to “downloader” folder and delete the file “cache.cfg”. Then go back to Magento Connect and retry

**Try these on a non-production server first.**